# What's the lowest time complexity solution to merge two "deque"s?

Tags: python, arrays, time-complexity, deque

```
from collections import deque

dq1 = deque([...])  # with n length
dq2 = deque([...])  # with m length
```

we want to left-extend dq2 to dq1 (with left to right order) and then, keep the dq1.

**question1:** if the best solution depends on the **n** and **m**?

I tried the following solutions:

scenario1: (`n > m`)

```
for _ in range(len(dq2)):
    dq1.appendleft(dq2.pop())
```

scenario2: (`n < m`)

```
dq2.extend(dq1)
dq1 = dq2  # question2
```

**question2:** what's the time complexity of specified line? `O(1)` or `O(n+m)`?

**question3:** Are there any better solutions than these I have mentioned for 2 scenarios?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to merge two deques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53139531/fastest-way-to-merge-two-deques)

Comment: Thanks for your time,
It's useful method and I can use it in scenario 2, but what about scenario 1?

Comment: But in a large scale, they seem to matter. for example: n=200, m=200000 is different compared to n=200000, m=200.
It seems that I shouldn't use same method for these two scenarios.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych: It's not constant time. I'm not sure why you would think it is. (The implementation can't just hook up the second deque's internal unrolled linked list to the tail of the first deque's unrolled linked list, if that's what you're thinking.)

Comment: @ahmdnz: What do you actually mean by "left-extend dq2 to dq1 (with left to right order) and then, keep the dq1"? If we have `dq1 = deque([1, 2])` and `dq2 = deque([3, 4, 5])`, what should the deques contain after your desired operations?

Comment: thanks for your attention @user2357112,

my desired result is:  `dq1=deque([3, 4, 5, 1, 2])`

Comment: @ahmdnz: What about `dq2`? What should that be?

Comment: `dq2` doesn't matter.

Comment: if I change my solution of scenario 1 to `dq1.extendleft(dq2.reverse())`, It seems that both solutions of two scenarios are good enough. but when I should use each one? the conditions (`m>n` and `m<n`) seem to be poor.

Answer (score 0):

change scenario 1: (n>m)

```
dq1.extendleft(dq2)
```

question 2:

```
O(min(m,n))
```

Comment: It would be useful for future readers if you could elaborate on why these are the answers, in your opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
But `dq1.extendleft(dq2)`  adds the **reverse** of dq2 to the left of dq1, I mean:
if `dq1 = [0, 1, 2]`, `dq2 = [-3, -2, -1]`, your code gives this result: `dq1 = [-1, -2, -3, 0, 1, 2]`

Comment: dq1.extendleft(dq2.reverse())

Comment: @zarrinkafsh your solution seems to be better than my `for` loop, It's should be faster.
Thank you!